# Qt: Sending signal to dead/stopped thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

I've come across the problem, that I might be sending signals from one `QThread` to another, however I have no way of checking if the thread that is implementing the `slot` is running. How will the framework handle such a situation while using `Qt::QueuedConnection` ?

```
...
WorkerImp* pWorker = new WorkerImp();
QThread worker;
pWorker->moveToThread(&worker);

QObject::connect(&worker, QThread::finished, pWorker, &QObject::deleteLater, Qt::QueuedConnection);
bool connected = QObject::connect(this, &SlaveMaster::requireWork, pWorker, &WorkerImp::doWork, Qt::QueuedConnection);
assert(connected);

// at this point we have connected the signal, thread is not starded.
// however the object that we use to connect still exists and will after we exit the thread.


worker.start();
worker.exit();
worker.wait();

// note that when we exit the QThread we do not destroy the object - it can be start over

emit requireWork();
...
```

Comment: You probably mean "to an object with affinity in a stopped thread", do you?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  In general, however, for a `QObject` to receive a signal via a queued connection the thread on which it exists (as returned by [`QObject::thread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread) *must* have an active event loop.

Comment: Is the signal discarded if the thread does not have active event loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signal is never handled. A queued connection across threads is posted as an event to the thread, handled by its event loop. If the thread is stopped (and thus its event loop), there is no one to pick up the event and deliver it:

From the Qt Docs [Signals and Slots Across Threads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads):

> Queued Connection: The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.

and [Per-Thread Event Loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop):

> [...] If no event loop is running, events won't be delivered to the object.

Note that a blocking queued connection would dead-lock

Comment: Yes, but does not say, what happens to the signal, is it discarded, is it put on some stack and will consume memory for nothing?

Comment: If no event loop is running, it will be queued in the target's thread until the event loop runs again.  If the code in that thread never calls `processEvents()` or similar, then it will sit there forever.  (I don't know if there's any cleanup when the thread exits, though).